# Using UUID with dashes in URLs

Tags: java, url, uuid

We have a small app written in Java with multiple Items, where user can visit each Item page, like **/path/uuid**.

My question is, it is fine to use uuid in urls with dashes? or should I remove the dashes?

Thanks.

Comment: It is fine. Better even, because that is the standard format for a UUID.

Comment: The use of hyphens in URLs is safe. It also helps to identify the path as a UUID. It only adds 4 chars to the final URL.